# On what basis is the conjunction $(A\to B)\land(A\to C)$ from $A\to B, A\to C$ allowed?

Tags: calculus, logic

I am going through a calculus book (up to $\Bbb{R}$) and I often come across the following scenario:
if we have proved the propositions: $A\to B$, $A\to C$ then we have $A\to B\land C$. It appears to me totally arbitrary that we conjugate the propositions $A\to B$,  $A\to C$ to  $(A\to B)\land (A\to C)$. On what basis is this conjugation allowed? Is it because both propositions follow from the same set of axioms?

I know that $$(A\to B)\land (A\to C)\Longleftrightarrow (A\to B\land C)$$ 
is a tautology. I just don't understand the part wherein two separate statements are conjugated.

Comment: If you know $P$, and you know $Q$, then you know $P\land Q$. This is the meaning of conjunction.

Comment: What does "conjugated" mean? Is it forming a conjunction like in $p \land q$?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, that's exactly what I mean by it.

Comment: The comma between the assumptions just means both have already been shown (or are assumed). So one can immediately put the two assumptions together with an "and" between them.

Comment: @coffeemath That's exactly the part which appears to be totally arbitrary to me and which I don't understand. Why not use an "or" between them etc.?

Comment: Just for your information, it's called "conjunction", not "conjugation"

Comment: Bright-- If one assumes *both* p and q it makes more sense to use "and" between them rather than "or" because "and" is stronger and one wants that for proofs from assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it in natural language (e.g. in english). If you have proved $A \implies B$, $A \implies C$; then you must know $A \implies B$ *and* $A \implies C$. From which you can use the tautology to derive what you need.

In a sense, the choice of **and** ($\wedge$) is arbitrary, because equally you could have used **or** ($\vee$), as you point out. However, by pointing this out, what you have shown is that it is both true that $A \implies B \wedge C$ and $A \implies B \vee C$. Given that the first one is more informative (gives you more information about what follows from $A$), it's the first one that is written in your textbook, and is the one that would be written in any mathematics text.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we take $(A\to B)\land (A\to C)$ as a premise.   Therefore $A\to B$ and $A\to C$ will hold by Conjunction Elimination   Should we assume $A$ also holds, then we may derive $B$ and also $C$, both by Conditional Elimination (*modus ponens*).   When $B$ and $C$ are both derivable, so too is $B\land C$ by Conjunction Introduction. Since $B\land C$ may be derived from an assumption of $A$ , therefore we deduce $A\to(B\land C)$, by Conditional Introduction.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{A\to B\land A\to B}{A\to B\\ A\to C\\\fitch{A}{B\\C\\B\land C}\\A\to(B\land C)}$

The converse is proven similarly.

Comment: The conjunction makes sense to me when I think about it in terms of derivation, but it doesn't make any sense when I merely think of propositions as being true or false. Since when we "derive", in case of each proposition, we use the same rules of derivation and hence, based on that, it makes sense to use conjunction. On the other hand, if we used different "derivation rules" for each of the propositions, then it would not make any sense to use conjunction.